# How to exclude non-valued object properties when converting to JSON in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a piece of code that works but I want to know if there is a better way to do it. I could not find anything related so far. Here are the facts:

- I have an object with n properties.
- I want to convert this object to JSON using (ConvertTo-Json).
- I don't want to include in the JSON those object properties that are not valued.

> Building the object (not really important):

```
$object = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TableName -Value "MyTable"
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value "Lorem ipsum dolor.."
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AppArea -Value "UserMgmt"
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InitialVersionCode -Value ""
```

> The line that I need improvements (to filter out the non-valued properties and not include them in the JSON)

```
# So I want to 'keep' and deliver to the JSON only the properties that are valued (first 3).
$object | select -Property TableName, Description, AppArea, InitialVersion | ConvertTo-Json
```

> What this line delivers:

```
Results:
{
    "TableName":  "MyTable",
    "Description":  "Lorem ipsum dolor..",
    "AppArea":  "UserMgmt",
    "InitialVersion":  null
}

What I want to obtain:
{
    "TableName":  "MyTable",
    "Description":  "Lorem ipsum dolor..",
    "AppArea":  "UserMgmt"
}
```

> What I've tried and works, but I don't like it since I have much more properties to handle:

```
$JSON = New-Object PSObject

if ($object.TableName){
   Add-Member -InputObject $JSON -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TableName -Value $object.TableName
}

if ($object.Description){
   Add-Member -InputObject $JSON -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $object.Description
}

if ($object.AppArea){
   Add-Member -InputObject $JSON -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AppArea -Value $object.AppArea
}

if ($object.InitialVersionCode){
   Add-Member -InputObject $JSON -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InitialVersionCode -Value $object.InitialVersionCode
}

$JSON | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to perform the same action on nested objects as well ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$object = New-Object PSObject

Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TableName -Value "MyTable"
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value "Lorem ipsum dolor.."
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AppArea -Value "UserMgmt"
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InitialVersionCode -Value ""

# Iterate over objects
$object | ForEach-Object {
    # Get array of names of object properties that can be cast to boolean TRUE
    # PSObject.Properties - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.properties.aspx
    $NonEmptyProperties = $_.psobject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Value} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    # Convert object to JSON with only non-empty properties
    $_ | Select-Object -Property $NonEmptyProperties | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "TableName":  "MyTable",
    "Description":  "Lorem ipsum dolor..",
    "AppArea":  "UserMgmt"
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; however, I suggest using `$null -ne $_.Value` in the `Where-Object` script block, so that you don't accidentally omit `0` and `$False` values too.

Answer (score 6):

I have the following function in my profile for this purpose. Advantage: I can pipe a collection of objects to it and remove nulls from all the objects on the pipeline.

```
Function Remove-Null {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        # Object to remove null values from
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline,Mandatory)]
        [object[]]$InputObject,
        #By default, remove empty strings (""), specify -LeaveEmptyStrings to leave them.
        [switch]$LeaveEmptyStrings
    )
    process {
        foreach ($obj in $InputObject) {
            $AllProperties = $obj.psobject.properties.Name
            $NonNulls = $AllProperties |
                where-object {$null -ne $obj.$PSItem} |
                where-object {$LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -or -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($obj.$PSItem)}
            $obj | Select-Object -Property $NonNulls
        }
    }
}
```

Some examples of usage:

```
$AnObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    prop1="data"
    prop2="moredata"
    prop5=3
    propblnk=""
    propnll=$null
}
$AnObject | Remove-Null

prop1 prop2    prop5
----- -----    -----
data  moredata     3

$ObjList =@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        notnull = "data"
        more = "sure!"
        done = $null
        another = ""
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        notnull = "data"
        more = $null
        done = $false
        another = $true
    }
)
$objList | Remove-Null | fl #format-list because the default table is misleading

notnull : data
more    : sure!

notnull : data
done    : False
another : True
```

Comment: Elegant and nicely done, I've added this to several of my modules now

Answer (score 3):

[beatcracker's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33039561/45375) offers an effective solution; let me complement it with a streamlined version that takes advantage of PSv4+ features:

```
# Sample input object
$object = [pscustomobject] @{
  TableName = 'MyTable'
  Description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'
  AppArea = 'UserMgmt'
  InitialVersionCode = $null
}

# Start with the list of candidate properties.
# For simplicity we target *all* properties of input object $obj
# but you could start with an explicit list as wellL
#   $candidateProps = 'TableName', 'Description', 'AppArea', 'InitialVersionCode'
$candidateProps = $object.psobject.properties.Name

# Create the filtered list of those properties whose value is non-$null
# The .Where() method is a PSv4+ feature.
$nonNullProps = $candidateProps.Where({ $null -ne $object.$_ })

# Extract the list of non-null properties directly from the input object
# and convert to JSON.
$object | Select-Object $nonNullProps | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my own modified version of [batmanama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394307) that accepts an additional parameter, letting you remove elements that are also present in the list present in that parameter.
For example:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | 
Remove-Null -AlsoRemove 'Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth' | Format-Table
```

I've posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bashenk/bc21a9879248f0a0b20ab9e55feac378) version including PowerShell documentation as well.

```
Function Remove-Null {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        # Object from which to remove the null values.
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,Mandatory)]
        $InputObject,
        # Instead of also removing values that are empty strings, include them
        # in the output.
        [Switch]$LeaveEmptyStrings,
        # Additional entries to remove, which are either present in the
        # properties list as an object or as a string representation of the
        # object.
        # I.e. $item.ToString().
        [Object[]]$AlsoRemove = @()
    )
    Process {
        # Iterate InputObject in case input was passed as an array
        ForEach ($obj in $InputObject) {
            $obj | Select-Object -Property (
                $obj.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object {
                    -not (
                        # If prop is null, remove it
                        $null -eq $obj.$_ -or
                        # If -LeaveEmptyStrings is not specified and the property
                        # is an empty string, remove it
                        (-not $LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -and
                            [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($obj.$_)) -or
                        # If AlsoRemove contains the property, remove it
                        $AlsoRemove.Contains($obj.$_) -or
                        # If AlsoRemove contains the string representation of
                        # the property, remove it
                        $AlsoRemove.Contains($obj.$_.ToString())
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the process block here automatically iterates a pipeline object, so the ForEach will only iterate more than once when an item is either explicitly passed in an array—such as by wrapping it in a single element array `,$array`—or when provided as a direct argument, such as `Remove-Null -InputObject $(Get-ChildItem)`.

It's also worth mentioning that both mine and batmanama's functions will remove these properties from *each* individual object. That is how it can properly utilize the PowerShell pipeline. Furthermore, that means that if any of the objects in the InputObject have a property that *does not* match (e.g. they are **not** null), an output table will still show that property, even though it has removed those properties from other items that *did* match.

Here's a simple example showing that behavior:

```
@([pscustomobject]@{Number=1;Bool=$true},
[pscustomobject]@{Number=2;Bool=$false},
[pscustomobject]@{Number=3;Bool=$true},
[pscustomobject]@{Number=4;Bool=$false}) | Remove-Null -AlsoRemove $false

Number Bool
------ ----
     1 True
     2
     3 True
     4
```

Comment: I would suggest changing `IsNullOrEmpty` to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. With your current function, properties with more than one space I.E. `"    "` will remain after processing. Otherwise, an excellent solution.